# Why is a Wait cursor being displayed for a modal dialog in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, mouse-cursor

I am launching a modal dialog from the MainWindow in a WPF application by doing something like this.

```
SomeView view = new SomeView();
view.ShowDialog();
```

The Modal dialog contains  a combo box inside to let the user select an option and then return to the main application. Problem is when ever the user hovers the mouse over the modal Dialog(SomeView) , it gets a Busy cursor. If the user moves the mouse outside the area of the ModalWindow( into the MainWindow's real estate), the cursor goes back to normal. But when ever it is inside the modal window, the cursor shows busy. However, the user is able to click and proceed with the application.

If I launch the window as modeless , by calling

```
SomeView view = new SomeView();
view.Show();
```

Then I do not see the busy cursor.

Does any one have a clue on why it is happening? or ways to find out the rootcause. I am able to fix the issue by doing the following, but I wanted to understand the rootcause. Also Setting the cursor property on the ModalWindow is not helping.
The following works.

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = System.Windows.Input.Cursors.Arrow;
window.ShowDialog();
Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
```

Thanks in advance.
Sumit.

Comment: This is not the expected behaviour and your issue is not reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Make sure that you don't set the Mouse.OverrideCursor property somewhere in your dialog window or in any control that is used in this window.

Comment: @mm8 I can reproduce it on my machine. ShowDialog() causes the new window to have the Busy cursor while the parent window has a normal cursor (backwards to what one might expect). I'm running VisualStudio 2015 with .NET 4.6.01055